# WK8 R2 Server, installed WAMP on second IP: Lost local host on IIS7

Tags: iis-7, windows-server-2008-r2

I have installed WAMP on a secondary IP, which works great;

I used the following article to make the changes:

http://www.iislogs.com/steveschofield/iis7-post-44-iis7-and-apache-on-the-same-machine

Wamp/Apache works great, but now I cannot see my localhost; Im expecting to see the IIS7 homepage.

I can only see the wamp server homepage using the secondary IP address.

My host file looks like:

127.0.0.1       localhost

xxx.xx.xxx.xxx example.com.au

I would appreciate any help on this please, any thought?

Thank you in advance.

Joseph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either edit the hosts file to resolve localhost to the IP address that IIS is on (if that's where you're expecting localhost to be), or don't bind WAMP to 127.0.0.1, and have IIS's localhost website bind to 127.0.0.1.